# Using XSD to generate CS file Produces Much Larger Class

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xsd.exe

I'm trying to update an XML to accept a currentYear value.

So I added: `<xsd:element name="currentYear" type="xsd:string"/>` to the .xsd file.

I then ran xsd and it generated a file.

This file is 10x the size of the previous .cs file.

Before it was generated with: Runtime Version:4.0.30319.239
The new file I generated was using: Runtime Version:4.0.30319.269

Would this make a big difference?

With the new .cs file I generated I can no longer compile.

Comment: Show us some relevant code/XML.

Comment: Need more info. What command line options did you give xsd to produce the original file?  What command line options to produce the current file? What is different between the old file and the new file? And what compile errors are you getting now? Did anyone manually edit down the original file?

Comment: It's not your main question, but if you want a current-year value, you'd probably do better with `xsd:gYear` not `xsd:string`.

Comment: Everything else is already setup for a string. The issue ended up being the command I was using to create the file. I was using xsd /dataset /language:CS XSDSchemaFile.xsd, and everything worked fine once I tried xsd /classes /language:CS XSDSchemaFile.xsd

Comment: @NMunro Welcome to stak overflow. Please make your last comment an answer to the question, and in in a day or so: accept that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue ended up being the command I was using to create the file. I was using xsd /dataset /language:CS XSDSchemaFile.xsd, and everything worked fine once I tried xsd /classes /language:CS XSDSchemaFile.xsd